# Is there any reason to move a long-interval NSTimer to a background thread?

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` event that fetches currency rates every 15 minutes or so. If I have the timer running on the main thread, but the action it triggers is on a background thread, will my application suffer a loss of performance? Should I put the timer on a background thread; or is having it on the main thread absolutely fine, as it doesn't use any of the application's performance until fired, each 15 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, keep the timer on the main thread.  Timers require a runloop, which only the main thread provides for you.  Background threads that wish to use timers must run their own runloop.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the runloop hint, i wasn't sure why i couldn't make it work on background thread in the first place :) As long as it is not hogging up the main thread I am fine with it. I would assume code execution will continue after NSTimer starts?

Comment: Yes.  Timers are not synchronous.  If they were, everyone would just use `sleep()` instead :)

Comment: The only hitch to having it on the main thread is that it will not fire when the main thread is busy doing something.  Your code has to return up to the run loop to allow the timer to fire.  If your code kept the main thread busy with some big calculation or something, the timer would not fire during that time.  Of course you shouldn't be doing things like that on the main thread anyway, probably, but it's worth noting this caveat for posterity.

Comment: @bhaller, that's true no matter which thread the timer is running on.  And, as you imply, it's more likely a background thread would be involved in a long running process than the main thread.